# WCF Websocket project fails upon Entity Framework data access attempt

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, websocket

I am new to WebSockets (this AM) and have set up a WCF WebSocket app that works when doing a trivial example I found online (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619343/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part).

I added Entity Framework and as soon as I add code to try to access data the process (just sending a message back and forth) no longer works.

Could there be some fundamental concept I could be missing?

Does anyone have any good ideas for troubleshooting?

```
namespace PBWebSocket
{
    public class PBWebSocket : IBWebSocket
    {

        private SPEntities db = new SPEntities();

        public async Task SendMessageToServer(Message msg)
        {
            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPBCallback>();
            if (msg.IsEmpty || ((IChannel)callback).State != CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] body = msg.GetBody<byte[]>();
            string msgTextFromClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            var reqId = Int32.Parse(msgTextFromClient);

            // *** The below line breaks it ***
            var req = db.Requests.Where(r => r.Id == 164).FirstOrDefault();

            reqId = reqId + 2;
            Message newMsg = ByteStreamMessage.CreateMessage(
            new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqId.ToString())));
              newMsg.Properties["WebSocketMessageProperty"] =
            new WebSocketMessageProperty
              { MessageType = WebSocketMessageType.Text };

            await callback.SendMessageToClient(newMsg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be building a poco that is declared via `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes.

Comment: I don't believe that is relevant to the problem I am facing.  It may be futile but I was hoping to gain knowledge about why the process fails as soon as I add the code `db.Requests.Where(r => r.Id == 164).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: To pass an object through WCF you have to define the object via attributes I mentioned.

Comment: I understand but I am not even using the object in the faulty code above, my plan was to try to perform a `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on the object then turn that into a `Message`.  It wasn't working and I kept removing code until I found out that the one call to try to access the DB was causing it to fail.  I have a couple other WCF services here that already access that DB so it's odd to me that this is happening and am trying to find the cause for failure.  I am attempting to write a unit test to step through it but am running into problems.accessing a client object in the test.